# Removing compound worded named entities from a document using spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

How can one use spaCy to remove named entities from a text if some of the named entities are compound words?

I am aware of the question at [Removing named entities from a document using spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313461/removing-named-entities-from-a-document-using-spacy/62563019#62563019)
I believe this is not a duplicate of that question, because the accepted answer posted there will fail if the Named Entities are compound words.
Example code for why the accepted answer to the linked question fails appears below.

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text_data = 'This is a text document that speaks about entities like New York and Nokia'

document = nlp(text_data)

text_no_namedentities = []

ents = [e.text for e in document.ents]
for item in document:
    if item.text in ents:
        pass
    else:
        text_no_namedentities.append(item.text)
print(" ".join(text_no_namedentities))
```

Output:

```
This is a text document that speaks about entities like New York and'
```

What is the best way to remove named entities from text, including compound word entities?
Thanks.

P.S. I would have posted this as a comment to the linked question, but as a new user I lack sufficient reputation to comment.  I tried posting it as an answer there, but since I don't know the solution (only that the accepted answer will fail with compound words) it wasn't a good answer and was deleted.  A new question seemed to be the last recourse left to me, but if this was not appropriate any advice as to the correct course of action in a situation like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a token is part of a named entity, its `token.ent_type_` attribute will be of that entity type even if it is part of a compound named entity. You can achieve what you are looking for using the code below as follows:

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

text_data = 'This is a text document that speaks about entities like New York and Nokia. My name is John Smith'

doc = nlp(text_data)

# You can add other Named Entities types that you would want to remove to the list
text_without_ne = [token.text for token in doc if token.ent_type_ not in ['GPE', 'PERSON']]

print(" ".join(text_without_ne))
```

**Output**

```
This is a text document that speaks about entities like and . My name is
```